# Jquery: Passing JSON values as parameter to function with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

The situation is this:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {

        $('#bullets').append('<li id="demo" onclick="loadCards(\'' + element.id 
                    + '\','+index+')"><a href=\'#\'>' + element.name + '</a></li>');

});
```

This is adding an inline javascript `onclick` and calls the function `loadCards` with two parameters `id` and `name`.

Works fine in normal web application but am creating a chrome extension and figured out the inline javascript is not supported.

I tried to add `event-listener` but am not able to pass the parameters. I tried adding following code after the loop:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelector('#demo').addEventListener('click', loadCards( ));      
});  // have to pass id and name in loadCards.
```

How can I pass id and name from above JSON to the event listener?

Answer (score 1):

Try below: set values as data attributes and read it in click event handler

```
$(function(){
  $.each(data, function(index, element) {
     $('#bullets').append('<li id="demo" data-id="' + element.id + '" data-index="' + index + '" data-name="' + element.name + '"><a href=\'#\'>' + element.name + '</a></li>');
   });

   $(document).on('click', '#bullets li', function(){
        var id=$(this).data('id');
        var name= $(this).data('name');
        loadCards(id, name); 
    });
});
```

Comment: that's index and not name I believe?

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

the argument to `addEventListener` needs to be a function reference, not a call to the function.

```
document.querySelector('#demo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    loadCards(param1, param2 ); 
});
```

Comment: The thing is, param1 and param2 are extracted from the loop but this call is outside that. Should I store both params as global variable and then pass?